# Qt - Not using correct source files

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I have several Qt projects which create dlls. I then have a 'main' project which loads them all and displays a GUI. Everything runs fine.

My problem is, I now have ANOTHER Qt project (lets call it NEWEST project) in which I need to incorporate the main project...so everything seems like it's working, but when I do changes to one of the dll projects, those changes do not get propagated to the NEWEST project. I rebuild and copy over the dlls, but the project still executes old files. I have stepped through it with the debugger, and in places where I have commented lines out, those lines get executed.

I know it's hard to follow this, so please let me know if I can be more specific, or if you don't understand something.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
If I run the 'main' project on its own, however, the changes do get applied. fyi.

Comment: Probably you need to configure dynamic linker search path properly. Qt is irrelevant here.

Comment: @ulidtko ok....so how do i update the dynamic linker search path property??

Comment: that greatly depends on your OS. On Linux, you must learn `ld.so` and `ldconfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Qt IDE is using old binaries while running. `So Go to your build directories of your two projects and remove all those binaries generated in previous builds`.Now if you make changes to any file in your new integrated project it will be reflected, because it doesn't have old binaries to run. So qt IDE will compile the new updated source and run the latest binaries.